# Jabber accounts

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

How can I setup a jabber server with a set of accounts.  I would like to either edit a config file, or setup the accounts one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

What's the environment going to be?

In any case, I'm going to suggest looking at [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) - it's easy to set up, and if you happen to be setting up in a Windows Active Directory environment you can get it to use AD for account information (with a bit of fiddling).

Comment: We are currently using Openfire.  The administration is a breeze and is extremely feature-full.  We are using it w/ LDAP, but you can use internal accounts to add one at a time too.

Comment: I've also used Openfire for an internal chat system at a former company.  It was quick to configure LDAP authentication via the Active Directory, too.  Or you could easily add internal users piecemeal.